# One reducer in Custom Partitioner makes mapreduce jobs slower

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hadoop2

Hi i have an application that reads records from HBase and writes into text files.
Application is working as expected but when tested this for huge data it is taking 1.20 hour to complete the job .
Here is the details of my application

1. Size the data in the HBase is 400 GB approx 2 billions records .
2. I have created 400 regions in the HBase tabl so 400 mappers .
3. I have used custom Partitioner that puts records into 194 text files.
4. I have lzo compression for map output and gzip for final
   output.
5. I have used md5 hashing for my row key

I have used custom partitioner for my data segregation .
I have 194 partitioner and reducer and all reducer  gets completed very fast except last two that has very huge no of records because of the condition .

I don not  know how handle this situation.

My condition is such that two partitoner will get large no of records and i can not change that also .

All reducer gets completed within 3 minutes but because of that overall job takes 30 mintes of time .

Here is my implementation

```
hbaseConf.set("mapreduce.map.output.compress", "true");
hbaseConf.set("mapreduce.map.output.compress.codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec");

FileOutputFormat.setOutputCompressorClass(job, GzipCodec.class);
```

My Partitioner logic is here

```
if (str.contains("Japan|^|2017|^|" + strFileName + "")) {

    return 0;

} else if (str.contains("Japan|^|2016|^|" + strFileName + "")) {

    return 1;

} else if (str.contains("Japan|^|2015|^|" + strFileName + "")) {

    return 2;

} else if (str.contains("Japan|^|2014|^|" + strFileName + "")) {

    return 3;

} else if (str.contains("Japan|^|2013|^|" + strFileName + "")) {

    return 4;
}
```

Comment: Can i ask what you're doing in your reducer? Having looked at previous questions, it wasnt clear why you needed it.

Comment: i have to trim  some column names from the Hbase records so that i will have correct records in the reducer output files.I can not remove in the map side as based on those extra column my logic is written in the Partitioner class

Comment: I would really not write a partitioner like this, you should construct an appropriate key in your mapper. If you have a few reducers that are taking a long time because they have a lot of records, then the first thing to do is make your key (or partitioner) in this case more granular. I assume you know whats in your data and why a few of the reducers are getting a lot of data, you need to split it up more, ie split on the year and month, so instead of 1 key you get 12.

Comment: Your input set has a lot of records having "Japan|201X".

Simplest way would be to add "Japan|{month}|201X" or use multi-outputs to achieve the same.

Comment: @KrazyGautam there is no months in the records thats the problem i am facing .

Comment: @BinaryNerd i can do that without reducer also actually reducer is not required in my case .But i have 200 regions in my HBase table so when i do scan 200 mapper gets initiated and instead of creating 40 files that i need it create 200 output files per reducer.So do you think can i handle it without reducer in my case

Comment: @KrazyGautam i can do that without reducer also actually reducer is not required in my case .But i have 200 regions in my HBase table so when i do scan 200 mapper gets initiated and instead of creating 40 files that i need it create 200 output files per reducer.So do you think can i handle it without reducer in my case

Comment: @KrazyGautam also i will have too many if else condition to handle in my custom partitioner class  around 2k i dont know how to handle that writing that does not seems to be smart coding .