# How to remove combiner output and keep only reducer output in mapreduce final output

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

Hi i am running an application which reads records from HBase and writes into text files .

I have used combiner in my application and custom partitioner also. I have used 41 reducer in my application because i need to create 40 reducer output file that satisfies my condition in custom partitioner.

All working fine but when i use combiner in my application it creates map output file per regions or per mapper .

Foe example i have 40 regions in my application so 40 mapper getting initiated then it create 40 map-output files . But reducer is not able to combine all map-output and generate final reducer output file that will be 40 reducer output files.

Data in the files are correct but no of files has increased .

Any idea how can i get only reducer output files.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs;

public class CommonCombiner extends Reducer<NullWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text> {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CommonCombiner.class);
    private MultipleOutputs<NullWritable, Text> multipleOutputs;
    String strName = "";
    private static final String DATA_SEPERATOR = "\\|\\!\\|";

    public void setup(Context context) {
        logger.info("Inside Combiner.");
        multipleOutputs = new MultipleOutputs<NullWritable, Text>(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void reduce(NullWritable Key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        for (Text value : values) {
            final String valueStr = value.toString();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if ("".equals(strName) && strName.length() == 0) {
                String[] strArrFileName = valueStr.split(DATA_SEPERATOR);
                String strFullFileName[] = strArrFileName[1].split("\\|\\^\\|");

                strName = strFullFileName[strFullFileName.length - 1];


                String strArrvalueStr[] = valueStr.split(DATA_SEPERATOR);
                if (!strArrvalueStr[0].contains(HbaseBulkLoadMapperConstants.FF_ACTION)) {
                    sb.append(strArrvalueStr[0] + "|!|");
                }
                multipleOutputs.write(NullWritable.get(), new Text(sb.toString()), strName);
                context.getCounter(Counters.FILE_DATA_COUNTER).increment(1);


            }

        }
    }


    public void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        multipleOutputs.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean that combiner creates output files? it shouldn't work like that. combiners are run on map-side as a local reducer and then it's the reducers that produce the output files. tmp files written by the mappers (in local filesystem, not HDFS) are deleted after the job completion.

Comment: If you dont want the combiner, just comment it out.

Comment: @BinaryNerd yes when i use combiner many small output files are getting created .and if i comment out combiner class my job becomes slow .

Comment: @BinaryNerd i am getting combiner output that is the problem .If i am using reducer i should get reducer output finally .

Comment: Are you saying your reducer isn't doing anything when you include the combiner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't outputting any data from your combiner for the reducer to work with. In your combiner you're using:

`multipleOutputs.write(NullWritable.get(), new Text(sb.toString()), strName);`

Which isn't how you write data out for use between stages, ie from a mapper or combiner to the reduce phase. You should be using:

`context.write()`

MultipleOutputs is just a way to write extra files to disk where you need more than one. I've never seen it used in a combiner.

Comment: Thanks and it helped ..But there is one problem that i am facing .I have custom partitioner and because if that one of the reducer gets huge data and makes overall job slower .All other reducer gets completed very fast except two reducer which has very huge data .I have separate question for that .Here is the link .Request you to please suggest something .[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43112385/custom-partitioner-makes-mapreduce-jobs-slower)

Answer (score 0):

Lets get the basics clear

1. Combiner is a optimization and can run both at mapper as well as in reduce (merge phase of reduce) (fetch merge reduce phases ).
2. Find out distribution of keys in your data , does a given mapper access lot of same key if yes, then combiner is helping else it has no effect.
3. 1 K regions no where gurantees that they are equally partitioned.  You are having some hot regions
4. Find the hot regions and split.

Please follow : http://bytepadding.com/big-data/map-reduce/understanding-map-reduce-the-missing-guide/

Comment: In my case combiner is working but i am getting combiner output as rivate.INC-m-00196.gz but not reducer output.I have edited my question please have look once

Comment: Can you please explain "but not reducer output" , where are you seeing INC-m-00196.gz  local fileSystem or HDFS ?     If the file is on HDFS it means its a map only job.